# When are SQL Server Views updated?

Tags: sql-server, view

I have two tables that are around 500k rows each (and growing). Inserts/Updates happen to these constantly, sometimes 100's per minute. The system is having performance issues, namely timeouts, on basic inserts into these tables. We've tuned our indexes, and done the usual optimizations. But I'm wondering if the fact that these two tables are referenced in 5 views with heavy joining might be detrimental.  I always thought, maybe mistakenly, that as underlying tables change, the views that reference them change too. So if the tables are changing that much, maybe our system is getting overwhelmed by having to constantly play catch-up updating views.

Comment: Both responses are accurate. A view is essentially shorthand for using a subquery in a join. There are a number of reasons that your timeouts can be occurring; since you said timeout and not deadlock I'm assuming the inserts are being called from outside of SQL. Can you provide some more information on how the timeouts are occurring? It could be that you have your timeout threshold set too low (for example, with a SqlCommand object).

Comment: I am a pretty big opponent for the usage of views in stored code. If you can use a view then you can also write the joins manually and not use the view. The problem with a view is that you're trying to use a one stop solution for scenarios that most likely do not require the entirety of the solution. Keep in mind that SQL is pretty good at optimizing itself and it does this based upon the tables used and the specific columns being use from each table. If your view returns 6 columns, but you only need four then your query is inherently inefficient due to the view.

Comment: @Love2Learn - not entirely true. If you only select 4 columns from the view, the optimizer can use that information and produce a plan that would be unable to supply the other columns, if such a plan is viable. As I said, they optimization applies across the whole query (with the view definitions expanded into it).

Comment: We do get deadlocks too but mostly timeouts. And you're correct, our website calls Stored Procs that have the insert/update code. I'll look into timeouts though. I believe we have them upped a bit but maybe not enough.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'll have to look into that then, what you're saying does make sense; I always thought the subquery results were evaluated and passed back, but it makes sense that if one of the columns is not used that the optimizer could/would exclude it from the entirety of the query logic. On the table usage side, you still take a performance hit if you join to a table and don't use anything from that table within a view, correct???

Comment: @Love2Learn: see my answer `1)`. The view is based on three tables but the final query uses only four columns from two tables.

Comment: @KaneJeeves: start SQL Profiler, intercept `Deadlock graph` events and publish one of this deadlock graphs (XML format / *.xdl).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about coding and should be asked on the database administrators site

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Unless* they're [indexed views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) (you haven't mention such in your question), they're not "updated" at all.

Normal views are similar to a macro in C - they're just a convenient shorthand to hide a part of a larger expression. They're expanded out into the parse tree of whatever statement references them, and the entire tree is then compiled and optimized - at the point of usage.

---

For indexed views, you would be largely correct - the views are maintained as part of the same transaction that performs changes in the base tables. However, the rules for indexed views have been designed so that this update activity shouldn't incur too large a penalty (they can be maintained without having to re-query the entire base table).

Comment: Definitely not Indexed views. I'll look elsewhere for issues, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It depends:

1) If the view is not indexed, then view is expanded

```
-- View definition
CREATE VIEW Sales.v_SalesOrderDetail
AS
SELECT  h.SalesOrderID, h.SalesOrderNumber, h.OrderDate, 
        d.SalesOrderDetailID, d.OrderQty, d.UnitPrice, d.LineTotal, 
        p.ProductID, p.Name AS ProductName, p.Color AS ProductColor
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail d ON h.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN Production.Product p ON d.ProductID = p.ProductID
GO

-- View usage
SELECT  v.SalesOrderDetailID, v.OrderQty, v.UnitPrice, v.ProductName
FROM    Sales.v_SalesOrderDetail v
WHERE   v.ProductColor='Red';
GO
```

If we look at the execution plan (SSMS: Ctrl + M), 
[image]
then we will see that the view (`FROM Sales.v_SalesOrderDetail v`) is expanded and the server queries just two tables: `Sales.SalesOrderDetail d` and `Production.Product p`. More, we can see how the join between `Sales.SalesOrderHeader h` and `Sales.SalesOrderDetail d` is removed because:

- the `SELECT` clause (`SELECT v.SalesOrderDetailID, v.OrderQty, v.UnitPrice, v.ProductName`) doesn't includes columns from `Sales.SalesOrderHeader` table,
- between this two table there is a foreign key constraint and
- this FK constraint is trusted.

2) If the view is indexed (meaning that there is an `UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX` defined on the view) and the SQL Server edition is enterprise then the view could be expanded **or not**. If the edition <> enterprise then indexed view is expanded. We can force the server to *not expands* the [indexed] view by using `NOEXPAND` hint:

```
-- View definition
CREATE VIEW Sales.v_SalesOrderDetail2
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT  h.SalesOrderID, h.SalesOrderNumber, h.OrderDate, 
        d.SalesOrderDetailID, d.OrderQty, d.UnitPrice, d.LineTotal, 
        p.ProductID, p.Name AS ProductName, p.Color AS ProductColor
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail d ON h.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN Production.Product p ON d.ProductID = p.ProductID
GO

-- Defining the UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_v_SalesOrderDetail2
ON Sales.v_SalesOrderDetail2 (SalesOrderDetailID);
GO

-- View usage
SELECT  v.SalesOrderDetailID, v.OrderQty, v.UnitPrice, v.ProductName
FROM    Sales.v_SalesOrderDetail2 v WITH (NOEXPAND)
WHERE   v.ProductColor='Red';
GO
```

In this case, we can see that the execution plan 
[image]
includes the `Clustered Index Scan PK_v_SalesOrderDetail2` operator. So, it uses the index defined on the second view.

Be aware: [SQL Server bug indexed view + MERGE](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2013/02/06/incorrect-results-with-indexed-views.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

SQLServer views are not cached, so everytime you request a view the query is executed

Answer (score -1):

Tuning indexes is good but it might be worth considering how often and when you update stats on these indexes.  Also, using a buffer table to hold inserts that can then be inserted as bulk operation every 5 or 10 minutes or whatever is suitable for your system may help (putting this on a separate physical disk would be a good idea.)  Doing this would make selects much faster 90% of the time and not much worse than current the other 10% of the time.